# Negative lookbehind or tempered pattern for checking one two or three words before a string

Tags: r, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a code that would identify supporting terms (i.e. 'detect' 'evidence') unless there is a negation term **up to 3 words before**.

Some examples:
"FISH tests did not detect BCL2 translocation"
"FISH tests did not provide evidence of a BCL2 translocation"

I tried using lookbehind, but since it requires an exact length I can't have a the flexibility of looking back 1-3 words.

I tried using a tempered dot, but it gives any number of words.

The code I currently have, looks only a single word before the 'support diagnosis' term.

`grepl("(?<!\\bnot\\b\\s|cannot\\s|n't\\s|\\bno\\b\\s|negative\\s)(reveal|seen|show|detect|demonstrate|confirm|identif|evidence|suggest|positive|observe)(?:(?!\\bnot\\b)(?!cannot)(?!n't)(?!\\bno\\b)(?!negative for)(?!, ).)*?(bcl-?2|14[q]?[;:]18)"), y, perl=TRUE,ignore.case = T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookbehind doesn't help in this situation, what you can do is to systematically search the negative terms and to discard parts of your string using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` up to three words:

```
(\\bnot\\b|\\bcannot\\b|n't\\b)(?:\\W++(?!(?1))\\w+){0,3}(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(reveal|seen|show)\\b(?!\\snot\\b)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great !!! I changed `(?1)` to `(?-1)` so that the reference would be relative (i.e. to the last capturing group before the pattern). I am still trying to fully understand the notion of _consuming_. In this case would _w+_ and _w++_ function the same ?

Comment: @user2387584: In `\W++`, the possessive quantifier forbids the backtracking, it's useful here when the following negative lookahead `(?!(1))` fails. This way the non-capturing group fails quicker. Note that you can obtain more or less the same effect writing: `(?:\W+\b(?!(?1))\w+)` because of the pcre auto-possessification mechanism.